# how to change 4 columns of StringSplit criteria with linq in vb.net

Tags: string, vb.net, linq, split, idictionary

I'm trying to filter a DataGridView with multi criteria column in one textbox in vb.net.

The code below `DoFilter2()` can only be used for column names `Criteria1`

so I can use for columns  `Criteria1`,`COLORCODE`,`SIZE`,`INFO`

Please Guide Me

Thanks

```
Private Sub DoFilter2()
        BeginInvoke(
        New Action(
        Sub()
            If TXTCRITERIAALLINONE.Text.Trim().Length = 0 Then
                DataGridView1.DataSource = StockCardsCache
                Return
            End If

            Dim dict = TXTCRITERIAALLINONE.Text.Split({","}, StringSplitOptions.None).
            Take(4).
            Select(Function(x, i) New With {.Index = i + 1, .Word = x.Trim()}).
            Where(Function(x) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Word)).
            ToDictionary(Function(pair) $"Criteria{pair.Index}",
            Function(pair) pair.Word)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = StockCardsCache.
 Where(Function(StockCardsCache) StockCardsCache.IsFilterItem(dict)).ToList()
        End Sub))
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class StockCardsNEW
    Public Property Invono() As String
    Public Property InvoDate() As Date
    Public Property Transaction() As String
    Public Property CodeProduct() As String
    Public Property Barcode() As String
    Public Property Criteria1() As String
    Public Property COLORCODE() As String
    Public Property SIZE() As String
    Public Property INFO() As String
    Public Property [IN] As Integer
    Public Property [OUT] As Integer
    Public Property BLC As Integer

    ' Replace `.Equals` with `.Contains` if needed...
    Public Function IsFilterItem(dict As IDictionary(Of String, String)) As Boolean
        Return dict.All(
            Function(kv) ContainsProperty(kv.Key) AndAlso
            GetPropertyValue(Of String)(kv.Key).
            Equals(kv.Value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    End Function

    Private Function GetPropertyValue(Of T)(propName As String) As T
        Return DirectCast(Me.GetType().GetProperty(propName)?.GetValue(Me), T)
    End Function

    Private Function ContainsProperty(propName As String) As Boolean
        Return Me.GetType().GetProperty(propName) IsNot Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```